# Turkish Airlines: can I drop off my luggage more than 3 hours before departure in Istanbul?

Tags: luggage, turkish-airlines

I have a stopover in Istanbul for few days. Outbound flight with Turkish Airlines departs at 2 am and I'd like to drop off the luggage not 2 hours before departure, at midnight, but 8 hours, let's say at 6pm. Meanwhile, I don't want to come to the airport and stay with luggage before check-in desk for 6 hours before check-in opens.

With Emirates I did it in Dubai 20 hours before departure and there were no problems with it. Does somebody have similar experience with Turkish in Istanbul?

I know that the best answer is to call and ask them directly. I did it. Twice and I got different answers. I have a strong feeling that their agents don't know the answer...

Comment: "the best answer is to call and ask them directly" -> that's definitely not the best answer because as you've noticed the customer support by phone is often not reliable (and probably not liable either).

Comment: I don't know the specifics of Turkish Airlines but in my experience they will take it as long as there is an open counter and if it's less than 24 hours before departure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've succeeded to drop my luggage 5 hours before departure in the new Istanbul airport even if everybody told that it was impossible. No questions from the agent at all.